# button押下で、削除の実行とページ遷移したい

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

buttonをクリックし、name='action'がPOSTされたら、DELETEをexecute();しているのですが、
このとき、同時にhome.phpへ遷移させたいです。

`<button type='submit' name='action' value='delete' onclick="location.href='home.php'">`
だったり、
`if ($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {$stmt->execute(); header("Location: ./home.php");}`
なども試したのですが、うまくいきませんでした。

いろいろ調べて試したのですが、自分の力では、遷移と削除のどちらか一方しか一度に実行できませんでした。
方法をご存知の方、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE url = :url");
$stmt->bindValue(":url", $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
echo "<form method=\"post\"><button type='submit' name='action' 
value='delete'>Delete</button></form>";
if ($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: もしくはbutton押下で、javascriptでダイアログ（削除実行／キャンセル）を表示させるとともに、元の画面はhome.phpに遷移させてしまう。
というのは可能でしょうか

Comment: 「うまくいかない」が「どううまくいかない」のかを書かないと回答貰えないと思います。

Comment: そうですね。質問文の意味では、ページ遷移できないということです。削除を実行する場合、DB上では削除されていますが、画面上はデータが表示されたままで、ページ遷移もされません。（そして遷移するコードの場合は、削除がされません。）

Answer (score 2):

上記のコードが action=delete 自の処理だとした場合、中でechoしてしまうと php はヘッダを出力してしまいます。
つまり後から

```
header("Location: ./home.php");
```

を実行しても移動しなくなってしまいます。また削除の prepared statement が作られているのに if の中だけでしか実行していないのも気になります。

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE url = :url");
    $stmt->bindValue(":url", $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    header("Location: ./home.php");
    return;
}
```

こう書くと action=delete 時に削除クエリを実行し、その後画面遷移してくれるかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。提示頂いたコードを試したところ、buttonを押すと、Deleteボタンの隣に配置しているTweetボタン（これは今タグだけで、機能させていません）が表示されなくなるという現象が起きました。つまり、表示はともかく画面は更新されているようですが、ページ遷移されず同じphp内に留まっている状況です。

Comment: ちなみに button タグの回りに `<form>` タグは書いておられるでしょうか？

Comment: Tweetの`<button>`タグの周りには書いてないです。→`<button id="tw">Tweet</button>`

Comment: 書きましょう。。。。。。。。。

Comment: `<form><button>Delete</button><button>Tweet</button></form>`としても、`<form><button>Delete</button></form><form><button>Tweet</button></form>`としてもダメですね...。

Comment: form に method と action を書きましょう。

Comment: すみません、返信用に簡略化して書いておりました。actionをhome.phpと指定すればそこへ遷移するのですが、それでは削除のロジックが実行されません。。

Comment: であればあとは button に name=action value=delete があれば home.php に遷移し、パラメータが渡っているので上記の if 文の中に入るはずだと思います。

Comment: 多分if文の前にタグ（`<head>`？）など出力している部分があるのでしょう。
それよりも前にif文を持ってくると大丈夫なはずです。
前のコメント http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/19541/12301#comment18177_19541 のようなこともおそらく必要ないと思います。

Comment: @TugrebIc ありがとうございます。`<head>`出力してました...。`<html>`の前に記述したところ、ボタンを押すと真白のページになるようになりました。また、home.phpに遷移しておらず、同じphpファイルでした。せっかくお力添えいただいたのに解決出来ずすみません...。

Comment: 真っ白なページが出るのは if 文がどれも通らずすり抜けたか、途中でエラーが出たのだと思います。dump_r 等を使って少しずつどこでエラーになっているか確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど・・。技術的にはまだまだ浅薄な知識しかありませんので、一旦UIを変更する形で対処し、余裕のできた時点で立ち戻りたいと思います。すみません。。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptでbuttonの押下時の処理を制御するのはどうでしょうか？

```
document.querySelector("button[name='action']").onclick = function() {
  var data = { "name": "John Doe", "age": 25 }; // POSTするデータ
  var url  = "./action.php"; // POST送信先URL
  var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.timeout   = 1000 * 30;
  xhr.onload    = _onXHRLoad;
  xhr.onerror   = _onXHRError;
  xhr.ontimeout = _onXHRTimeout;
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

  /**
   * 非同期通信成功時の処理
   */
  function _onXHRLoad(ev) {
    location.href = "./home.php";
  };

  /**
   * 非同期通信エラー時の処理
   */
  function _onXHRError(err) {
    console.error("Error:", err);
    return false;
  };

  /**
   * 非同期通信タイムアウト時の処理
   */
  function _onXHRTimeout(err) {
    console.error("Error:", err);
    return false;
  };
};
```

Comment: Kazma Arakakiさま、ご回答ありがとうございます。すこし質問させてください。削除の処理が自ファイル_content.php_内にある場合（つまり パラメータを他ファイル_home.php_に渡したい訳ではない場合）、POST送信先URLにはどちらを設定すべきですか？

Comment: @rrrnnnn _content.php_です。POSTは削除処理のあるファイルに送信します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`var data`に今の私のコードの何を入れたらよいか分からなかったので、UIを変更する方向で解決したいと思います。せっかくなのに、申し訳ありません。